# Method polymorphism / inheritance in AngularJS 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing problem with controllers overriding in AngularJS.

Here comes the problem:

```
    function UiCoreController($scope, ...) {
        'use strict';

        angular.extend(vm, {
            validatePremium: validatePremium
    }

        function validatePremium() {
            console.log('validate premium in core controller');
            // validation logic 
            vm.calculatePremium();
        }

        function calculatePremium() { ... }
    }

function UiAskController($rootScope, $scope, $controller) {
    'use strict';

    var vm = this;
    var core = $controller('UiCoreController', { $scope: $scope });

    angular.extend(this, core);

    angular.extend(vm, {
      ...
    }
    function calculatePremium() { ... }
}
```

When I call `validatePremium()` method from template (by `ng-change` directive) - it is called from `UiCoreController`, but `calculatePremium()` is not called by more descriptive `UiAskController::calculatePremium()`.

That works only if copy-paste whole `validatePremium()` method to `UiAskController` but it seems to me like code duplication.

Would anyone help me achieving the calls to `calculatePremium()` in Java-like code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is not OOP like Java and therefore there is  no  polymorphism and inheritance.  So short answer is **no**. You cannot achieve what you want by using controllers only. The function `calculatePremium` is bind to controller scope and for sure you don't want to share scopes between controllers.

You can write this method to `$rootScope` but its not good practice

---

I would put `vm.calculatePremium()` logic into service. Its a right place to make this kind of stuff.

Keep in mind that main purpose of controllers is to bind your data to DOM a.e. render view by using scope.

Since `Service` is a singleton, all data manipulations you can do in services to avoid code duplicate and make code maintenance easy

Comment: I have read about putting in services, but still I would like to know how to solve issue in main topic.

Comment: @mlewandowski well, if you looking for similar behavior of polymorphism | inheritance like in Java - short answer - no. I updated the answer